# the table columns are not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US"><head><title>saookivabuion (IT saookivabuion) 'jkop 09yam9'</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:jkop-dev%40LOPINK.com" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jkop.css" />
<script language="javascript" src="/js/jkop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body onload="jkop_form_focus(); " bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<!-- po78NAME: dws-rch-ymadghe-l.LOPINK.com -->



          <!-- little bit of whitespace -->
          <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
          <table border=0 width=100%>
<tr valign="top">
    <td align=left>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align=center width=30%>
<form class="case_form" name="case" action="/itsm/saookivabuion_management/open-case/jkop+saookivabuion+Management/po78+hu899000st" method="get" target="_blank">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border=0 width=95% align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td>

      <table border="1" bgcolor="EEEEEE" width="100%" align="center">
<tr align='center' bgcolor='#669999'>
    <td colspan='4'><font color='#FFFFFF' size='5' ><b>saookivabuion</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">saookivabuion Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">saookivabuion Category</th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">Status in saookivabuion Portfolio</th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">hjueadt lopitiey</th>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
    <td><a href="/nnklolpu/view-appl/14096">jkop 09yam9</a></td>
    <td>IT saookivabuion</td>
    <td>njio09tauial</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th bgcolor='#CCCC99' colspan='4'>saookivabuion Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='4' align='left'>PLP oolaged jkop saookivabuion, <a href='http://09yam9.LOPINK.com'>09yam9</a> is a 0O9-opcolledd a9999o oooooest olkl.  hjo ooop hakes oure renkuest requests for aaavvv89, routes these requests for approval, and creates Help Desk tickets or queues for creation agents to pick up.     </p>     <p>     <b>5o9i80rING:</b> 5o9i80ring is only in effect for the j90 RCDN origins, but all other j90 servers are listed for ooo09e ksjsai9808 0oikjhyu.     </p>

<a href='http://wikicentral.LOPINK.com/confluence/display/PROJECT/09yam9+-+Business+Support+Services'>09yam9 Businsess Support Services</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr noshade width="75%">
<table border="1" bgcolor="EEEEEE" width="100%" align="center">
<tr bgcolor="#CCCC99">
    <th colspan=2>
         OPIkaoi jsot mlipgnoonts (mko098ins) 
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td valign="top" width="30%" bgcolor=#EEEECC><br>
ooop uoi may janugen or rkkke this saookivabuion from po78(s).<p>
o To <i><b>jkloisn</b></i> to 09sts, bea8888 for po78s, 6ele8t the po78(s) you wish to jkloisn to, and click 'jkloisn to po78(s)...'.<p>

o To <i><b>edit</b></i> hu899000sts, 6ele8t the hu899000st(s) you wish to edit and click 'Edit hu899000st...'.<p>

o To <i><b>remove hu899000st(s)</b></i>, 6ele8t the hu899000st(s) and click 'Remove'.  iuu bi99 be ppploted to oplikj the po0ppl.<p>

o hu899000sts created here bi99 use hjueadt 00ntacts and 5o9i80r 6e88ingss ppp00s
overridden for specific po78s. To <i><b>boverri61</b></i> 6e88ingss for a specific po78, including 5o9i80ring parameters and contacts, jump to the boverri61s section.<p>

   </td>
   <td valign="top" width="70%" align="center">
<br><form name='myForm' action='/nnklolpu/edit-appl/14096/po78_hu899000sts' method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="_ACTION_" value="SAVE"> 
<input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="APPL" > 
<input type="hidden" name="APPLID" value=14096 /> 
<input type="hidden" name="ACTION" value="" />
<table border=0 cellspacing=10>
<tr bgcolor=#CCCCEE>
    <th>banai9le po78s</th>
    <td rowspan=3 bgcolor=#AAAAAA width=1>&nbsp;</td>
    <th>Here goes the table</th>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
  <td valign=top nowrap>
  <table class="po78selform" border="1"
         cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="100%" align="center">
        <div class="header">po78names<br><6ele8t name="_hgm_dropdown_sel" style="font-size: xx-small">
<option  value="-4">                    [Custom List(below)]</option>
<option  value="83183000">ACS 5.x Dev po78s</option>
<option  value="83163000">ACS 5.x Prod po78s</option>
<option  value="83165000">ACS 5.x Stage po78s</option>
</6ele8t>

        </div>
        <textarea name="_po786ele8tor_field" rows=5 cols=40 style="font-size: small"></textarea>
        <div class="buttonlike">
          [ <a target="po786ele8tor" href="/tools/po786ele8tor/po786ele8tor.pmcgi?atab=&targetfield=myForm._po786ele8tor_field&multi_6ele8tor=1" onClick="window.open('/tools/po786ele8tor/po786ele8tor.pmcgi?atab=&targetfield=myForm._po786ele8tor_field&multi_6ele8tor=1', 'po786ele8tor', 'scrollbars,width=800,height=600'); return false;">bea8888</a>
            <img src="/images/icon_popup.gif" alt=" ">    
      ]
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
  <td valign=top nowrap>
      <!-- starts here -->


      <div>   <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Endpoint descr</th>
                    <th>Assigned Host</th>
                    <th>Endpoint priority</th>
                    <th>Monitor Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
    </table></div>


    <div  style="max-height: 100px; overflow: auto;">
        <table id="test"  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <tbody><tr id = "tr_390245">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390245 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390245 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-c1-1-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-c1-1)</td>
    <td>TYO</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390243">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390243 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390243 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-c1-2-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-c1-2)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390244">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390244 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390244 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-d1-1-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-d1-1)</td>
        <td>SYD&RTP&BLR</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390242">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390242 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390242 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-d1-2-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-d1-2)</td>
        <td>RTP&BLR</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393881">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393881 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393881 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>dws-rch-ionsj98kl-l</td>
        <td>(test by jayesh aug)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393882">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393882 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393882 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>dws-rch-ionsj98kl-l</td>
        <td>(test by jayesh aug2)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_391602">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_391602 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=391602 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(support-ref-test)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393262">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393262 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393262 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(P1 P2 tests)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
        </table>
    </div></td>
</tr>

<tr align=center>
    <td>
<input type="button" name="return" value="BUTTON 1 " onClick="return openSection('/nnklolpu/view-appl/14096')"/>         <input type="submit" name="STORE" value="BUTTON 2 ..."  /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="STORE" value="BUTTON 3 ..."  />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="STORE" value="BUTTON 4 "  />
    </td>
</table>

</form><br>   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
<HR><BR>
<P><FONT SIZE="-1">BOLPI98087 &copy; LOPINK 67y651ns ok01c. 1008</FONT></body></html>
```

The table with the heading "Here goes the table" is my concern.

1. It is working fine in all Firefox, IE, Safari and chrome
2. When the table scrolls , the header does not dissapear.

Problem is the header and the table data (tr and td) beneath not aligning properly.

I am trying to fix it by giving a width to the header divs and then the same width to the according table td, using css classes. But I am not an expert of html and css hence struggling.

Please help me out, but the above points (#1, #2 )should still work.

thanks.

Comment: A fiddle displaying your issues would help greatly

Comment: In case you are asking yourself what [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is

Comment: The fiddle is here http://codepen.io/ragecub3/pen/ucfIa

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code:
link:http://codepen.io/ragecub3/pen/ucfIa

```
!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US"><head><title>saookivabuion (IT saookivabuion) 'jkop 09yam9'</title>
<link rev="made" href="mailto:jkop-dev%40LOPINK.com" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jkop.css" />
<script language="javascript" src="/js/jkop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body onload="jkop_form_focus(); " bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<!-- po78NAME: dws-rch-ymadghe-l.LOPINK.com -->



          <!-- little bit of whitespace -->
          <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
          <table border=0 width=100%>
<tr valign="top">
    <td align=left>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align=center width=30%>
<form class="case_form" name="case" action="/itsm/saookivabuion_management/open-case/jkop+saookivabuion+Management/po78+hu899000st" method="get" target="_blank">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border=0 width=95% align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td>

      <table border="1" bgcolor="EEEEEE" width="100%" align="center">
<tr align='center' bgcolor='#669999'>
    <td colspan='4'><font color='#FFFFFF' size='5' ><b>saookivabuion</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">saookivabuion Name</th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">saookivabuion Category</th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">Status in saookivabuion Portfolio</th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCC99">hjueadt lopitiey</th>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
    <td><a href="/nnklolpu/view-appl/14096">jkop 09yam9</a></td>
    <td>IT saookivabuion</td>
    <td>njio09tauial</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th bgcolor='#CCCC99' colspan='4'>saookivabuion Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='4' align='left'>PLP oolaged jkop saookivabuion, <a href='http://09yam9.LOPINK.com'>09yam9</a> is a 0O9-opcolledd a9999o oooooest olkl.  hjo ooop hakes oure renkuest requests for aaavvv89, routes these requests for approval, and creates Help Desk tickets or queues for creation agents to pick up.     </p>     <p>     <b>5o9i80rING:</b> 5o9i80ring is only in effect for the j90 RCDN origins, but all other j90 servers are listed for ooo09e ksjsai9808 0oikjhyu.     </p>

<a href='http://wikicentral.LOPINK.com/confluence/display/PROJECT/09yam9+-+Business+Support+Services'>09yam9 Businsess Support Services</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr noshade width="75%">
<table border="1" bgcolor="EEEEEE" width="100%" align="center">
<tr bgcolor="#CCCC99">
    <th colspan=2>
         OPIkaoi jsot mlipgnoonts (mko098ins) 
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td valign="top" width="30%" bgcolor=#EEEECC><br>
ooop uoi may janugen or rkkke this saookivabuion from po78(s).<p>
o To <i><b>jkloisn</b></i> to 09sts, bea8888 for po78s, 6ele8t the po78(s) you wish to jkloisn to, and click 'jkloisn to po78(s)...'.<p>

o To <i><b>edit</b></i> hu899000sts, 6ele8t the hu899000st(s) you wish to edit and click 'Edit hu899000st...'.<p>

o To <i><b>remove hu899000st(s)</b></i>, 6ele8t the hu899000st(s) and click 'Remove'.  iuu bi99 be ppploted to oplikj the po0ppl.<p>

o hu899000sts created here bi99 use hjueadt 00ntacts and 5o9i80r 6e88ingss ppp00s
overridden for specific po78s. To <i><b>boverri61</b></i> 6e88ingss for a specific po78, including 5o9i80ring parameters and contacts, jump to the boverri61s section.<p>

   </td>
   <td valign="top" width="70%" align="center">
<br><form name='myForm' action='/nnklolpu/edit-appl/14096/po78_hu899000sts' method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="_ACTION_" value="SAVE"> 
<input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="APPL" > 
<input type="hidden" name="APPLID" value=14096 /> 
<input type="hidden" name="ACTION" value="" />
<table border=0 cellspacing=10>
<tr bgcolor=#CCCCEE>
    <th>banai9le po78s</th>
    <td rowspan=3 bgcolor=#AAAAAA width=1>&nbsp;</td>
    <th>Here goes the table</th>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
  <td valign=top nowrap>
  <table class="po78selform" border="1"
         cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td height="100%" align="center">
        <div class="header">po78names<br><6ele8t name="_hgm_dropdown_sel" style="font-size: xx-small">
<option  value="-4">                    [Custom List(below)]</option>
<option  value="83183000">ACS 5.x Dev po78s</option>
<option  value="83163000">ACS 5.x Prod po78s</option>
<option  value="83165000">ACS 5.x Stage po78s</option>
</6ele8t>

        </div>
        <textarea name="_po786ele8tor_field" rows=5 cols=40 style="font-size: small"></textarea>
        <div class="buttonlike">
          [ <a target="po786ele8tor" href="/tools/po786ele8tor/po786ele8tor.pmcgi?atab=&targetfield=myForm._po786ele8tor_field&multi_6ele8tor=1" onClick="window.open('/tools/po786ele8tor/po786ele8tor.pmcgi?atab=&targetfield=myForm._po786ele8tor_field&multi_6ele8tor=1', 'po786ele8tor', 'scrollbars,width=800,height=600'); return false;">bea8888</a>
            <img src="/images/icon_popup.gif" alt=" ">    
      ]
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
  <td valign=top nowrap>
      <!-- starts here -->


      <div style="max-height:100px;overflow: auto;">   <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Endpoint descr</th>
                    <th>Assigned Host</th>
                    <th>Endpoint priority</th>
                    <th>Monitor Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
    </table>



        <table id="test"  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <tbody><tr id = "tr_390245">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390245 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390245 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-c1-1-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-c1-1)</td>
    <td>TYO</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390243">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390243 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390243 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-c1-2-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-c1-2)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390244">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390244 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390244 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-d1-1-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-d1-1)</td>
        <td>SYD&RTP&BLR</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390242">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390242 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390242 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>acs-rtp1-d1-2-w</td>
        <td>(DND-jkpo-d1-2)</td>
        <td>RTP&BLR</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393881">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393881 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393881 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>dws-rch-ionsj98kl-l</td>
        <td>(test by jayesh aug)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393882">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393882 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393882 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>dws-rch-ionsj98kl-l</td>
        <td>(test by jayesh aug2)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_391602">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_391602 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=391602 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(support-ref-test)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393262">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393262 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393262 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(P1 P2 tests)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr>
    <!-- <tr id = "tr_393282">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393282 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393282 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(ace-simulate-auto-dep)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393643">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393643 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393643 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(Test-mko098in-APLMGT-493)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393864">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393864 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393864 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(test-create-mko098in)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393942">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393942 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393942 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-lophgak-l</td>
        <td>(jayesh testing for insert EP)</td>
        <td>AMS&BXB</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393863">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393863 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393863 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>dws-rch-bikjare-l</td>
        <td>(test-create-mko098in)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97038">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97038 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97038 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>eap-stg3-1-l</td>
        <td>(STAGE3 jobs)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393804">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393804 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393804 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>eap-stg3-1-l</td>
        <td>(test23)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97023">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97023 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97023 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>jkop-core</td>
        <td>(PROD j90)</td>
        <td>SYD&RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390983">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390983 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390983 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo-alln.composite</td>
        <td>(09yam9-Texas ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390982">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390982 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390982 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo-rcdn.composite</td>
        <td>(09yam9-Texas ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390946">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390946 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390946 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo-rtp1.composite</td>
        <td>(09yam9 ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>RTP</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_391823">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_391823 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=391823 ></td>
        <td>P2</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo-rtp1.composite</td>
        <td>(saookivabuion-jkpo- KABA-JEST ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>MTV</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390945">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390945 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390945 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo-rtp5.composite</td>
        <td>(09yam9 ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>RTP</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_391822">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_391822 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=391822 ></td>
        <td>P2</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo-rtp5.composite</td>
        <td>(saookivabuion-jkpo- BAVA-TEST ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>MTV</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390947">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390947 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390947 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo.composite</td>
        <td>(09yam9 ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>RTP</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390984">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390984 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390984 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo.composite</td>
        <td>(09yam9-Texas ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_391824">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_391824 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=391824 ></td>
        <td>P2</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-1-jkpo.composite</td>
        <td>(saookivabuion-jkpo- BAVA-TEST ACTIVE)</td>
        <td>MTV</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_392342">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_392342 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=392342 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>jkop-09yam9-rule.composite</td>
        <td>(jkop-09yam9-rule)</td>
        <td>BLR&RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_96993">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_96993 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=96993 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>esd-code</td>
        <td>(PROD dist)</td>
        <td>BLR&RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_392362">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_392362 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=392362 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>esd-code</td>
        <td>(09yam9-esd-code-rule)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393730">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393730 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393730 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>esd-code</td>
        <td>(tes65)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393731">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393731 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393731 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>esd-code</td>
        <td>(test)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97035">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97035 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97035 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>esd-stg3-1-l</td>
        <td>(STAGE3 dist)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_96995">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_96995 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=96995 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>j90-ams</td>
        <td>(AMS Composite)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_105314">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_105314 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=105314 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>j90-blr2</td>
        <td>(virtual)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97005">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97005 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97005 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>j90-bxb</td>
        <td>(BXB Composite)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97010">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97010 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97010 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>j90-hkk</td>
        <td>(HKG Composite)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393362">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393362 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393362 ></td>
        <td>P1</td>
        <td>j90-hkk</td>
        <td>(test-stage-p1)</td>
        <td>BLR</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97017">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97017 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97017 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>j90-rtp</td>
        <td>(RTP Composite)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97022">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97022 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97022 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>j90-jkopire</td>
        <td>(SIN Composite)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97031">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97031 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97031 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>j90-sydney</td>
        <td>(SYD Composite)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_97032">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_97032 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=97032 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>j90-tokyo</td>
        <td>(TYO Composite)</td>
        <td>SIN</td>
        </tr>
     <tr id = "tr_393870">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393870 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393870 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>grand-parent-link-test.composite</td>
        <td>(grand-parent-link-test)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_388222">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_388222 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=388222 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>test-addl</td>
        <td>(jkop-09yam9-test-addl-1)</td>
        <td>BLR&RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_389742">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_389742 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=389742 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>test-addl</td>
        <td>(09yam9-test-addl-rule)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_390902">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_390902 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=390902 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>test-addl</td>
        <td>(dsx)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393762">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393762 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393762 ></td>
        <td>P5</td>
        <td>test-addl</td>
        <td>(Test-KT-session)</td>
        <td>MTV&RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393866">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393866 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393866 ></td>
        <td>P3</td>
        <td>test-create-po78.composite</td>
        <td>(test-create-po78)</td>
        <td>RCH</td>
        </tr><tr id = "tr_393803">
        <td><input type=checkbox id=APMON_CONFIG_ID_393803 name=APMON_CONFIG_ID value=393803 ></td>
        <td>P6</td>
        <td>tools</td>
        <td>(test1)</td>
        <td>No pointers!</td>
</tr> -->

    </tbody>
        </table>
    </div></td>
</tr>

<tr align=center>
    <td>
<input type="button" name="return" value="BUTTON 1 " onClick="return openSection('/nnklolpu/view-appl/14096')"/>         <input type="submit" name="STORE" value="BUTTON 2 ..."  /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="STORE" value="BUTTON 3 ..."  />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="STORE" value="BUTTON 4 "  />
    </td>
</table>

</form><br>   </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
<HR><BR>
<P><FONT SIZE="-1">BOLPI98087 &copy; LOPINK 67y651ns ok01c. 1008</FONT></body></html>
```